# How to support different screen resolutions in iOS

Tags: ios

I want to know the icon sizes for iPhone and iPad.

How can i support different screen densities in iOS.

In my app icon are blur in iPad and iPhone5.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to make your images suit the resolution 
[image]
**[Check this LINK](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/MobileHIG/IconMatrix.html)**

Answer (score 3):

App Icon Sizes for iphone and ipad:

1. iOS 5 and 6 - 57pts at 1x and 2x:(57x57,114x114)
2. iOS 7 and 8 - 60 pts at 2x and 3x:(120x120,180x180)
3. iPad - 76pts at 1x and 2x:(76x76,152x152)

You can read [apple documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/MobileHIG/IconMatrix.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006556-CH27-SW1) to get better understanding.

Answer (score 1):

You may want to take a look at this:
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/MobileHIG/IconMatrix.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006556-CH27-SW1

Basically: for all included images you should provide two files, 1 named ie "picture.png" and the other "picture@2x.png" and iOS which to use for itself.

Answer (score 1):

You may get different icon sizes at following link :

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/MobileHIG/IconMatrix.html

Set Project icon images as @1x,@2x and @3x, it will automatically get images as per iOS device resolution.